Movesense: Gatt_SensorData_App error 507 Insufficient Storage

I am working on the Gatt Sensor Data app example code to communicate with Movesense either with another board or my phone using nRF Connect App. Although it used to send data normally, suddenly it stopped sending data and sends the packet {0x01, 0x99, 0x01, 0xFB}, which is HTTP_CODE_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE, when I try to subscribe for acceleration data.
Why does this happen and how can I deal with it?

In the same sample in the client code gatt_sensordata_app/web_client/index,
ACCDATA_REFERENCE = 99 is declared.
Where can I find the same reference numbers for gyroscope, magnetometer, temperature sensor in order to subscribe to these sensors ?


I was able to receive data properly by subscribing with the array [1,99,"/Meas/Acc/13"], but now it suddenly doesn't work.
I also tried to subscribe to other sensors as [1,99, "Meas/Temp"] and it worked once but now it doesn't. Could this cause the problem that it is stuck sending 507 error? If this is the case, I couldn't find the reference ids of the other sensors anywhere, and I would politely ask for some help on this matter too.

If you look at the (firmware code), you'll see that you have run out of subscriptions. The sensor supports max 4 simultaneous streams, and each subscription must be unsubscribed, which releases the space for new subscriptions.
